# Nodemailer sending emails but getting ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I don't why i'm getting this every time I try to use Nodemailer to send emails:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)

the thing is it's working but i'm getting this error, *by working I mean It sends the email*.

**The Code:**

```
    const sendEmail = async (email, subject, payload, template) => {
      try {
        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: "gmail",
          auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
          },
        });
    
        const options = () => {
          return {
            from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
            to: email,
            subject: subject,
            html: template,
          };
        };
        // Send email
        transporter.sendMail(options(), (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
            return error;
          } else {
            return res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
            });
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    };

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      if (!req.body.newsletterEmail) {
  
        return next(createError(400, "Please enter your email"));
        
      } else if (!req.body.newsletterEmail || !isEmail(req.body.newsletterEmail)) {
  
        return next(createError(400, "Please enter a valid email address"));
  
      }
        const checkEmail = await SubscribedEmails.findOne({ newsletterEmail: req.body.newsletterEmail });
        if (checkEmail) {
          return next(createError(400, "Email is already subscribed"));
        } else {
          //create new user
          const newSubscribedEmail = new SubscribedEmails ({

            newsletterEmail: req.body.newsletterEmail,

        });
        //save user and respond
        const SubscribedEmail = await newSubscribedEmail.save();
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Successfully subscribed",
          SubscribedEmail,
        });

        const link = `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/`;

        await sendEmail(
            SubscribedEmail.newsletterEmail,
          "Welcome to our newsletter!",
          {
            link: link,
          },
          `<div> <p>Hi,</p> <p>You are subscribed to our.</p> <p> Please click the link below to view more</p> <a href=${link}>GO</a> </div>`
        );
        return res.status(200).send(link);
        }
      
  
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
  
    }
  });
```

Comment: The problem is `sendEmail` also calls `res.status()` which is out of line. You can't do that once you've already committed to a particular response. That function shouldn't even know what `res` is.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to some quirks with using Gmail with Nodemailer. Review the docs here - https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

and configure your Gmail account here -
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Finally, you may run into issues with Captcha. Configure here - https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha